# Android: One cursor row for 2 joined tables

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have 2 tables, let's call them match and team. Match has a one to two relation with Team.

match has

```
_id = INTEGER PRIMARY
time = TEXT NOT NULL
team1_id = TEXT NOT NULL //references a team record
team2_id = TEXT NOT NULL //references a team record
```

team has

```
_id = INTEGER PRIMARY
name = TEXT NOT NULL
```

Each item of my list contains time, team1_name and team2_name. Populated by cursor. It looks something like this:

[image: List Item Image]

Now when I use join query:

```
Select match._id, time, team.name 
From match LEFT JOIN team
ON (team._id = match.team1_id OR team._id = match.team2_id)
```

I receive the following cursor result:

```
_id    time    name
42     6:00    Barca
42     6:00    Man City
```

What I am trying to achieve is have the two team names in two columns of the cursor instead of separate rows inorder to map it with the adapter's view i.e:

```
_id    time    team1    team2
42     6:00    Barca    Man City
```

Any tips on how to go about it?
Thanks.

Comment: @Rotwang **INNER** also gives me two rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do multiple joins and alias the column names:

```
SELECT match._id, 
       time, 
       t1.name AS team1_name,
       t2.name AS team2_name 
  FROM match 
  LEFT JOIN team AS t1 ON (t1._id = match.team1_id)
  LEFT JOIN team AS t2 ON (t2._id = match.team2_id)
```